# wcf service is disallowed due to cross origin policy

Tags: wcf

First url (my wcf) is not working (when i comment the 2nd url).. but 2nd does fine(an open api)

```
    var url = "http://localhost:26770/Service.svc/Employees";
    url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=sam&tomatoes=true&plot=full";
    var response = { success: false, message: 'Error' };
    var req = { method: 'GET', url: url, data: {} };        
    $http(req).success(function (data) {
        if (data != "0")
            response = { success: true, message: 'Wao' };
        else
            response = { success: false, message: 'invalid data' };
        alert(response.message);
    });
```

This http://localhost:26770/Service.svc/Employees works for me. Gives json data when accessed in browser. So it must mean WCF is running.. But when i use it in an application where other api url is working. It disallows due to cross origin request

I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF

I added global.asax to my service app and following code

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

I rebuilt the service application.. tested its url working in browser.. But still **unable to access results from this wcf service** in my other app on same host but different port= > (`cross domain`)

Comment: Sami, have you tried to pass the parameters with the object instead with the url?
Like this:
var req = { method: 'GET', url: url, params: {t:'sam', tomatoes: true, plot: 'full'} };
 });